# Deploy a webiste on IIS and reuse the automatically created DB from the project

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core

I published my site on a web server and it works very well (at least to access it) but I would like to use the DB that was automatically created when I was in a development environment.

I initially checked 'Individual account' by creating the project, made some changes (creation of roles, fields in the ASPnetUser table, etc), did some stuff and then publish it and now I would like to recover the  DB i had when i was working with Visual Studio on this app (the data inside does not matter to me).

When I published my site with Visual Studio 2017, I was asked to check the providerName and the context.
So I ticked both options leaving the basic information (System.data.SqlClient & connection string to my context (who's not the basic ApplicationDbContext)).

Then, browsing my site, I tried to connect to a login that existed in development on my machine but no way, I also tried to create a new account (thinking that this would regenerate a db) but no way either.

I looked on the internet but I found nothing, except for Microsoft but they use Azure, which does not interest me.

Could you guide me on the processes to follow (even just a link to a tutorial would be very useful)?

I still specify that the server is on Windows Server 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this, in my opinion, is to install a standalone MS SQL server on your machine and create the base of your project not on localdb, but on that server (you need just to change connection string in your Web.config to do it).

Comment: Thx for your reply, that was my backup solution in case it isnt possible. The thing is this DB is only needed to register/connect, after it i've another db which in connect it with an API. Otherwise, if i had only one DB i would have definitly did it myself on Sql server.

Comment: For small application it is OK. But having a standalone sever provides you much more flexible solution.

Comment: Ah, and just the basic staff: don't forget, that connection strings on the sever machine most probable are different from those, you had on computer you was developing on, so you need to set up connections strings in web.config anyway

Comment: Ok i'm still on it! I don't have the web.config file on .net core 2.2 (i didn't find it), i only modified the connectionString in appsettings.json (from now i still cannot reach my db :D)

Comment: Is there something special i also need to modify in my DB? It weird because i keep getting errors and the automatic asp tables are not created.

Comment: Yes, in Core it's appsettings.json. You should ensure, that the db server really exists and that you specify in connection string the credentials of a user, which has rights tor create a database on that server. If you run VS and IIS on the same machine, the same connection string as for VS will be OK. If those are two different machines, then  you must have an SQL server on the sever machine, on which you will create a new db. To use the same data, you can make a backup copy of a db from you development machine and restore in on you sever machine.